# Basic IPv6 Static Routing (Global Unicast Routing)

Tags: cisco, routing, router, ipv6, cisco-commands

I have a topology like this:

[image]

Every PC and router is configured with IPv6 addresses.

1. -PING from PC1 to R1 is OK
2. -PING from PC2 to R2 is OK
3. -PING from PC3 to R3 is OK
4. -PING from PC4 to R4 is OK

However, I need to ping from PC1 to PC4 with only static routing.

The question is this:

Configure all IPv6 static routes for remote networks on Central router by using global-unicast IP address as the next-hop IP address.

I'm asking how to add routes to the routing table.

Router 1 Table :

[image]

Router 2 Table :

[image]

Router 3 Table:

[image]

Router 4 Table:

[image]

Central Router Table :

[image]

Comment: Routing tables are empty for all routers? So maybe you should add some routes then...

Comment: Please provide the actual configurations and routing tables from every router.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text information. Copy the text, paste it into your question, and use the Preformatted Text feature (`{}`).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm asking how to add routes to the routing table

The same way that you would for IPv4, except where IPv4 uses the `ip route` command, IPv6 uses the `ipv6 route` command.

In R1, you could create a static route to `3000:4::/64`:

```
ipv6 route 3000:4::/64 2000:1:1:1::1
```

or possibly a default route:

```
ipv6 route ::/0 2000:1:1:1::1
```

and in the Central router, you would have:

```
ipv6 route 3000:4::/64 2000:4:4:4::a1
```

You will need to do the same on all the R routers, and for all the networks on the other side of the R routers on the Central router.

---

This type of question is easily answered by doing a simple search. Cisco maintains documents on all the features. For example, [*Implement Static Routes for IPv6 Configuration Example*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/ip-version-6-ipv6/113361-ipv6-static-routes.html).